# What are some recommendable wireless USB network adapters for Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, networking, usb, adapter

I recently built a new PC and though I bought a wireless USB network adapter, I later realized that it doesn't support Linux. What are some suggestions for good USB wireless adapters for Linux ? Either 150Mbps or 300Mbps is fine for me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a  shopping recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you will find this post a fountain of information:

[WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported)